# IntelliJ - Apply refactoring changes of a library to the consumer

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, refactoring

I develop a Java library (A), and uses it in an application (B).

A is built with Maven and deploys a jar to a private Maven repository.

B uses Maven pom file to consume the most latest version of A from the repo.

Now I would like to make an API change in A (e.g rename a public method) using IntelliJ refactoring abilities.

Can I configure the Intellij environment so that the refactoring in A would also be applied to all the usages in B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have opened both projects in the same project window in IntelliJ and the consumer refers to the same version of the library which is currently opened, then IntelliJ will find usages of the API in the consumer module.

Comment: I imported the library as an IntelliJ (maven) module to the consumer project, and indeed that did the trick.  BTW, IntelliJ finds usages and perform project-wide refactoring even if the library's source code is not at the same version as was stated in the consumer's pom file.